# Vuejs How to pass parent classes to child component in template

Tags: vue.js, parent-child

I'm trying to remember how to pass a parent's `:class` bindings to a specific child component within a template. For instance:

```vue
// parent-component.vue
<template>
  <child-component :class="['foo', bar, 'baz']">
</template>
```

```vue
// child-component.vue
<template>
  <div class="dont-want-classes-here">
    <h1 class="not-here-either">Someting v Important</h1>
    <sub-component :class="['want-parent-classes in-here', ...$parent.classes]">
  </div>
</template>
```

Do I need to create a new prop just for that purpose? is there a specific part of the Vue instance I can access from within the component?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to create a new prop just for that purpose?

Yes. Vue does not provide a way to customize how the class and style props are applied to the template. It will always apply them to the root element and you cannot change this.

However if it were a functional component, then you can do this. But that doesn't apply here.

> Is there a specific part of the Vue instance I can access from within the component?

You can access the class directly from the vnode:

```js
this.$vnode.data.staticClass  // for class="static"
this.$vnode.data.class        // for :class="dynamic"
```

Comment: thanks for the leads. Do I also have to set `inheritAttrs` to `false` to prevent the classes being applied to the root element? Or are those separate concerns?

Comment: No, `inheritAttrs` will not prevent the class being applied to the root element and there is no way to prevent Vue from doing it.